# Get the search value of a datatable from JS for use in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I'm a VB bod of late learning PHP & PDO etc

In the main I've managed to code most stuff without help but I'm stumped on the current problem...

I need to export the values from a filtered datatable to Excel.

So in PHP I can export the data from the database table to Excel Ok

But I need to identify the filter used on the datatable to use this in the SQL query of the separate export to Excel php.

So either I get the value entered in the search box of a datatable and pass this to the export php code to get the according DB values then export OR I somehow pass the filtered datatable to the export PHP as an array?

I found the following code https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48262/get-filter-search-value-on-page-load

This traps for the datatable search term entered and writes it successfully to the console but can I get that value into PHP to pass to the export php?

Failing that how do you convert the datatable to an array to pass to the export php. If passing an array to another piece of php is possible, how do I do this?

This array data will not be big if this is a good way of doing this problem but getting that console value out to the php is a better way?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Are you aware that dataTables has built in Excel download capabilities?

Comment: I wasn't so I will check this export functionality out, thanks